# Unable to connect to Azure VM remotely using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I have created a Azure VM using powershell. This is the script I have used.

```
$UserName = "admin"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "admin@123" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)    
New-AzureRmVm `
    -ResourceGroupName "RGN" `
    -Name "VName" `
    -ImageName "Imagename" `
    -Location "West US" `
    -VirtualNetworkName "Vnetname" `
    -SubnetName "default" `
    -Credential $psCred `
    -OpenPorts 3389
```

Now, I'm trying to communicate with this VM. This is the command I have used to establish a connection/session.

```
$UserName = "admin"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "admin@123" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($UserName, $Password)
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName VName -Credential $psCred
```

It is saying the username or password is not correct.Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong.Thanks!

Comment: open CMD, type mstsc to open Remote Desktop Connection, Can you directly RDP to your Azure VM with public IP address? Does the same error appear?

Comment: I'm able to do a RDP to the VM. But not able to connect through powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the rules of the VM which you want to connect on Azure portal. And then configure the WINRM in the vm. Add trusted IP in your PC.

For more details, see [Access Azure Windows VM through Powershell](https://www.assistanz.com/access-azure-windows-vm-through-powershell/).

Answer (score 0):

What I would use is "domain\admin" or "computer\admin" also go through the steps on this thread here. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1309

Comment: Hi, I have given the domain name. Still not able to login.

Comment: The other thing is try to peel back the layers of complexity. As a test disable the firewall if that does not work first get it working on a virtual machine on your local network.